# Change color of text in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap 4 if that matters, but I am trying to change the color of the texts within the anchor tags. I am using an external CSS file and can't seem to get it to work. This is probably a dumb question, but hey i'm new to front-end! Teach me wizards!

```css
#home_nav {
  background-color: #5680E9;
}
.home_text{
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid"  id="home_nav">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="display-2 home_text"><a href="/STEMuli_Website/HTML_Pages/Explore.html">Create</a></div>
          <div class="display-2 home_text"><a href="/STEMuli_Website/HTML_Pages/Explore.html">Explore</a></div>
          <div class="display-2 home_text"><a href="#">Your Library</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `.home_text a, .home_text a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}`

Comment: Let me know if that level of explanation in my answer (find it below) is helpful, or too much/little for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow and also welcome to coding frontend!

I'll try to give some explanation.

```
.home_text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

tells the browser to apply a white text color to elements that have the CSS class `home-text`.

`color` is also a so-called `inherited property` which means that child elements will also have `color: #ffffff;` (short: `color: #fff;`) **unless more specific rules state otherwise**.

In your case, the browser has `default styles` for many elements, including `<a>`. This is called *user agent stylsheet* and its rules apply unless overwritten by **your** css.

To overwrite a rule, your rule needs to be at least as specific as the user agent stylesheet rule.

The user agent stylesheet for anchors in e.g. Chrome looks like this:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This is using webkit (the engine behind chrome used to be called "webkit", thus the naming) specific syntax which you shouldn't let throw you off. The important part is that it holds a rule for `color` which you want to replace with your color `#fff`.

On top of that, browsers also have a different default color for links which have already been visited. You either need to define this for your links too (e.g. `#eee` for pages already visited) or simply add a second selector (separated from the first by a comma) telling the browser not only to apply your color to `a` elements, but also `a` elements in `visited` state. This is done by adding `:visited` to `a`.

To sum it up, if you want all links on your page to be white, you'd go with this:

```
a, a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}
```

If you want only `a` inside of elements that have `class="home_text"` to be white:

```
.home_text a, .home_text a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}
```

If you have any further questions, or if something is unclear, just ask in the comments!

Happy trip into frontend!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation friend!

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the style to 'a' specifically

```
.home_text a{
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.home_text a {
    color: blue;
}
```

If you don't want the underline then try this:

```
.home_text a {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use complete selector for css .. Ex. .home_text >a 
If still not working ..color must beihg set somewhere else. So check other css or write ! important for color.

Answer (score 0):

**Little advice**

Use the full path to an ID

```
#home_nav .home_text a
```

or

```
home .home_text a
```

Sometimes you save your nerves when the element does not want to change.